# Google Drive on Linux release date?

Tags: google-drive, linux

Is there a planned release date, or any information on, when Google will release Drive application on Linux?

Comment: Hi @Rubén, thanks for pointing out the downvote reason. Since you are here, I think that like me you hadn't find any up-to-date information about the release date. I think it's pointless to put links about sites saying that there is no release date defined yet. The question was to someone who had a direct contact with Google.

Comment: Hi @Federico! Instead of adding those links you could include how do you found them or what sources of information do you reviewed / contacted. Note: I Removed the previous content as I was advised to rephrase it. If you didn't checkout yet the following link, please do it: [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to Google Customer Service about two weeks ago and they said they are working on a Linux Drive software but they do not have a roll-out date yet.

Comment: Nice, same answer of 5 years ago

Answer (score 0):

There's no official (from google) drive support on linux that I know of, but if you're using GNOME you can view and copy google drive folders in Nautilus.

Go to Settings ⮕ Online Accounts, add a google account, and the corresponding Drive account should be visible in the side bar.